# Current tightest bounds for critical 3-SAT density

Tags: pr.probability, random-k-sat

I'm interested in the critical [3-satisfiability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem#3-satisfiability) (3-SAT) density $\alpha$. It's conjectured that such $\alpha$ exists: if the number of randomly generated 3-SAT clauses is $(\alpha + \epsilon) n$ or more, they are almost surely unsatisfiable.
(Here $\epsilon$ is any small constant and $n$ is the number of variables.)
If the number is $(\alpha - \epsilon) n$ or less, they are almost surely satisfiable.

The thesis *[Belief propagation algorithms for constraint satisfaction problems](http://www.maia.ub.edu/~maneva/papers/thesis.pdf)*  by Elitza Nikolaeva Maneva challenges the problem from the angle of belief propagation known in information theory. On page 13, it says $3.52<\alpha<4.51$ if $\alpha$ exists.

What are the best known bounds for $\alpha$?

Comment: See also question http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/1130

Answer (score 17):

Notwithstanding Friedgut's theorem about $k$-SAT, while we lack techniques to get to negligible $\epsilon$ for small $k$, it seems more useful to talk about the satisfiability threshold ($\alpha - \epsilon$) and the unsatisfiability threshold ($\alpha + \epsilon$) as separate entities.

The unsatisfiability threshold is known to be at most 4.4898, a slight improvement since Maneva's 2001 thesis.

- J. Díaz, L. Kirousis, D. Mitsche, X. Pérez-Gimenéz.  *On the satisfiability threshold of formulas with three literals per clause*, Theoretical Computer Science **410**, 2009, 2920–2934. [doi:10.1016/j.tcs.2009.02.020](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.tcs.2009.02.020) ([preprint from one of the authors](http://math.ryerson.ca/~dmitsche/DKMP09.pdf))

The satisfiability threshold is known to be at least 3.52, which is unchanged from the time of Maneva's thesis.

- A. C. Kaporis, L. M. Kirousis, E. G. Lalas.  *The Probabilistic Analysis of a Greedy Satisfiability Algorithm*, Random Structures and Algorithms **28**, 2006, 444–480.  [doi:10.1002/rsa.20104](http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/rsa.20104)

These bounds were recently cited by Achlioptas and Menchaca-Mendez as the best known to date.

- D. Achlioptas, R. Menchaca-Mendez.  *Unsatisfiability Bounds for Random CSPs from an Energetic Interpolation Method*, ICALP 2012, LNCS 7391, 1–12.  [doi:10.1007/978-3-642-31594-7_1](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-31594-7_1)

Answer (score 6):

There is a new 58 page paper (32 refs) accepted to STOC 2013,

> [Going after the k-SAT threshold](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1212.1682v1.pdf) by Coja-Oghlan and Konstantinos Panagiotou

that surveys and advances the area of determining the precise k-SAT threshhold, building especially from results borrowed from statistical physics. From the abstract:

> Here we develop a new asymmetric second
>   moment method that allows us to tackle this issue head on for the first time in the theory of random CSPs. This
>   technique enables us to compute the k-SAT threshold up to an additive $\ln 2 − {1 \over 2}
>  +O(1/k) \approx 0.19$.

*Coja-Oghlan, Amin; Panagiotou, Konstantinos*, [**Going after the $k$-SAT threshold**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/2488608.2488698), Proceedings of the 45th annual ACM symposium on theory of computing, STOC ’13. Palo Alto, CA, USA, June 1--4, 2013. New York, NY: Association for Computing Machinery (ACM) (ISBN 978-1-4503-2029-0). 705-714 (2013). [ZBL1293.68164](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1293.68164).