# Empirical probability of k-SAT satisfiability

Tags: random-k-sat

Given a random instance $I_m = I_m(n,k)$ of $k$-SAT with $n$ variables and $m$ clauses, what's the probability $I_m$ is satisfiable?

It's believed that there's a threshold above which satisfiability becomes less likely as $m/n$ increases. The reverse is true as $m/n$ decreases.

Is there an empirical formula for $3$-SAT and other $k$'s that describe the rate at which satisfiability becomes more/less likely as you move away from the threshold?

Comment: I don't think there is a formula. See Moshe Vardi's [talk](http://videos.birs.ca/2014/14w5101/201401231116-Vardi.mp4) about phase transition.

Comment: Tyr to use surround your latex code with $ to make it more readable.
I am unsure how you wanted it to display

Comment: what is an "empirical formula"?

Comment: @Kaveh - thanks for the video. Very enlightening.

Comment: @Sasho - Hoping to find an empirically good formula based on statistical observations (rather than necessarily having been rigorously proven)

Comment: See the answers at https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/14953/109 for several key references.  This actually seems borderline a duplicate of that question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

see eg sec 4.7.4 p103 of this thesis where a finite-size scaling formula based on a power law is applied and coefficients fit with experimental data.

- [PHASE TRANSITIONS OF BOOLEAN SATISFIABILITY VARIANTS](http://users.soe.ucsc.edu/~kolaitis/theses/bailey-dissertation.pdf), Bailey 2004

Comment: fyi/addendum nobody called this out but full disclosure, that section seems to be on bounded SAT which is closely related to k-SAT but not the same. however the empirical formulas seem to be almost the same for k-SAT & they seem to have originated in statistical physics spin-glass transition point formulas. another ref [critical behavior in the computational cost of satisfiability checking](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/selman/papers/pdf/96.aij.critical_behavior_cost.pdf) 1996 Selman/Kirkpatrick see eg p276. [wish there were newer refs/study on this subj, havent seen them]